# Dictionary to Histogram

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, matplotlib, histogram

I have a dictionary called

`Samples = {5.207403005022627: 0.69973543384229719, 6.8970222167794759: 0.080782939731898179, 7.8338517407140973: 0.10308033284258854, 8.5301143255505334: 0.018640838362318335, 10.418899728838058: 0.14427355015329846, 5.3983946820220501: 0.51319796560976771}`

Here `keys` of the dictionary represent the points in the x-axis, and the `values` of the dictionary represent the values of the point of that particular `x` ie `y=f(x)`.

How do i create a histogram out of it with `bin sizes=1` in the interval `0-10`

Comment: Do you mean the histogram of the keys, or the histogram of the values? Histogram is a frequency plot; I know of histograms of a dataset, but I don't know of histograms of a *function*.

Comment: @Andrey SObolev: Histograms of the values falling within a range of keys where each bin is of size 0.1

Comment: @VeilEclipse did you check the answer below?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply!! Thank you for that!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `keys` as bin positions and the `values` as weights of the histogram, doing the following:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

d = {5.207403005022627: 0.69973543384229719, 6.8970222167794759: 0.080782939731898179, 7.8338517407140973: 0.10308033284258854, 8.5301143255505334: 0.018640838362318335, 10.418899728838058: 0.14427355015329846, 5.3983946820220501: 0.51319796560976771}
a = np.array(d.items())
a = a[np.argsort(a[:,0])]
x, weights = a.T

plt.figure(figsize=(5,4))
plt.hist(x, weights=weights)
plt.show()
```

which gives:

[image]